# Issue with Full-Text (FTS) master merge on SQL Server 2012 SP2

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

On my current project we have really annoying issue with master merge process that occurs after Full Population of FTS Index.

Let me describe our process: we have continuous build that setup environment and run unit tests after each commit in our source control. For each run we create new DB (on the same SQL Server) then fill it with test data and run unit tests. Sometimes unit tests failed because FTS Index population cannot finish in time.

We have constantly seeing in [sysprocesses] table lots of sessions with wait type **FT_MASTER_MERGE** that block our tests:
[image: FT_MASTER_MERGE]

In FTS log we have following error:

***The master merge started at the end of the full crawl of table or indexed view [TABLENAME] failed with HRESULT = '0x80000049'. Database ID is '45', table id is 706101556, catalog ID: 5.***

Here is an example of how we create FTS catalog and add table to it (As you can see it's created with **auto change tracking** together with **index update in background**):

```
    -- Create FTS catalog
    EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog 'WilcoFTSCatalog', 'create'
    EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'Users', 'create', 'WilcoFTSCatalog', 'PK_Users'
    EXEC sp_fulltext_column 'Users', 'UserId', 'add'
    EXEC sp_fulltext_column 'Users', 'Name', 'add'
    EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'Users', 'activate'
    EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'Users', 'start_change_tracking'
    EXEC sp_fulltext_table 'Users', 'start_background_updateindex'
```

Does anybody know what is the root cause of this issue and what should be done to avoid it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: OK, I think answer is here... - https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1069538/fulltextindex-master-merge-operation-was-not-done